# Como parsear una cadena json dentro de succes

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, asp.net

Hola estoy trabajando con columnas dinámicas y necesito parsear mi cadena data para convertirlo en un arreglo de objetos y asi poder acceder a sus elementos mediante un ciclo for. Pero al ejecutarlo muestra error en la consola. Espero me puedan ayudar a parsear  esta cadena.

Esta es la cadena que devuelve mi webMethod solo es una porción de la cadena ya que esta es muy larga.

```
"[\r\n  {\r\n    \"id_Persona\": 1,\r\n    \"Sucursal\": \"Mexico\",\r\n    \"Nombre\": \"Pedro\",\r\n
```

Este es mi WebMethod

```
[WebMethod]
public static string Persona(int id_Persona, string Sucursal, int id_Rol) 
{

    Transacciones t = new Transacciones();
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    DataTable tabla_Intervalo = new DataTable();
    DataTable tabla_imagenIntervalo = new DataTable();
    ds = t.Mostrar_Intervalo(id_Intervalo, Sucursal, id_Rol);
    tabla_Intervalo = ds.Tables[0];            
    tabla_imagenIntervalo = ds.Tables[1];

    string datos = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(tabla_Intervalo, Formatting.Indented);

    return datos;   

}
```

Esta es mi función que contiene a mi ajax

```js
function obtener_intervalo() {


    var persona = 1;
    var Sucursal = "";
    var id_Rol = 1;
    
    if (persona != 0) {

    
    var valores;
    var datafields_bonos = new Array();
    var columns_bonos = new Array();
    var columnsArray = [];

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "frmPersona.aspx/Persona",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: '{id_Persona:"' + persona + '",Sucursal:"' + Sucursal + '",id_Rol:"' + id_Rol + '"}',
        async: false,

        success: function(data) {
            alert("Entro correcto");

            if (data != '') {
                valores = jQuery.parseJSON(data); // Aqui cuando lo ejecuto me marca error en la consola.
                for (var i in valores[0]) {
                    datafields_bonos.push({ name: i });//No me regresa ningun valor
                    columns_bonos.push({ text: i, datafield: i, width: 200 });//No me regresa ningun valor
                }

                for (var j = 1; j < columns_bonos.length; j++) {
                    columnsArray.push(columns_bonos[j]);
                    console.log(columnsArray);//No me retorna el resultado
                }

            }

            var gridSource =
                {
                    localdata: valores,
                    datatype: 'json'
                   
                };
```

Este es el error en consola

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>) at Function.jQuery.parseJSON (jquery-1.11.1.js:8482) at Object.success (Prueba.js:91).
```

Cuando veo la estructura de data en concola (console.log(data)) me muestra esto.

```js
[↵  {↵    "id_Persona": 1,↵    "Sucursal": "Mexico",↵    "Nombre": "Pedro",↵ ...
```

Comment: Parece un poco extraño que aparezcan esos `\r\n` en tu json. Prueba a eliminarlos a ver si así te parsea la cadena correctamente.

Comment: Puesto que en tu petición AJAX, dices dataType: "json", no hace falta que parsees con JSON.parse, puedes acceder directamente al objeto con data.forEach por ejemplo o data.d[x].loquesea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo he solucionado colocando esto:

```
 valores = data.d; 
 valores = JSON.parse(valores);
```

Answer (score 1):

Hola creo que es porque estas usando mal la función, podrías intentar realizando lo siguiente:

```
valores = JSON.parse(data); // esto convierte la cadena en un objeto
```

Espero te sea de utilidad, podrías ver el siguiente link si tienes mas dudas, saludos.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17785592/difference-between-json-stringify-and-json-parse

Comment: Hola @Misael Arroyo he puesto lo que me comentaste pero me sigue marcando el mismo error.

Comment: Hola @SHINOBI quizás es por el tipo de cadena que devuelve el WebMethod, podrías intentar solo retornando la variable tabla_Intervalo, ejemplo: `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(tabla_Intervalo);`

Answer (score 0):

Como te dice Pikoh en los comentarios los `\r\n` tienen toda la pinta de ser los culpables.

Podrías tratar de eliminarlos o escaparlos a la hora generar el JSON, o podrías utilizar una solución similar a la de https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22723077/does-the-output-of-jsonconvert-serializeobject-need-to-be-encoded-in-razor-view .